# Azure Service Bus queue logging of messages taken from queue

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

We have a .NET Core 3.1 web-API application that listens to an Azure Service Bus queue.  We would like to get more information about the consumer of the messages on the queue - within our workflow, there should only be one (designated) consumer of a given queue, however we suspect there are multiple consumers.  We suspect this because there are no application log entries on the designated consumer application logs when (and after) a message on the queue is being processed.

To attempt to determine the consumer of a queued entry I have looked at the Service Bus Logs and queries related to AzureActivity and AzureDiagnostics however I couldn't find specific information about a message(s)/item(s) on a given queue

Can anyone shed any light on how I can find details about the consumer of a queued item ?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the information exposed to the clients. If clients are connecting using a connection string, you could reset the keys. If managed identity or service principal is used, find that in the portal.

Comment: Thanks @SeanFeldman - because it was in our Development environment, I finished up creating a new queue (different name) and deleted the original - it would be good to log the details of the consumer, but in this case I was able to work around the issue

Comment: Hello @TerrorBight, Could you please post an answer for the workaround that you have  achieved the requirement for your ask . Thank you.

Comment: Hi @AjayKumarGhose-MT - the workaround was simply to create a new Service Bus queue and abandon (delete) the old queue - then amend our codebase to write/listen to the new queue.  Also, as mentioned this is just a workaround - the original question was around how logs can be generated/viewed relating to the Service Bus queue - if anyone has further information regarding this, would be best if that is placed into the resolution (i.e. the workaround doesn't really answer the question regarding logs)